# Remove sudo permissions for one command

Tags: bash, command, sudo

this is probably a really simple question. I apologize if it is a duplicate.
I want to know how to remove sudo permissions for one particular command. I've created a script that installs a bunch of .deb packages and it needs sudo to do that, but one command in it needs to run without sudo permissions, so how would I do that? I'm using Ubuntu and this is a bash script.

I'm calling my script: ROS_install

Here is part of the script:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/forklift/Desktop/ROS/ros-hydro-laser-proc_0.1.3-0precise-20131015-2054-+0000_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i /home/forklift/Desktop/ROS/ros-hydro-urg-c_1.0.403-0precise-20131010-0128-+0000_amd64.deb

            sudo rosdep init
sleep 2
            rosdep update
```

The command "rosdep update" needs to be run without sudo permissions. I assumed that it was already, but I get a warning every time I run the script, and thus get locked out of the command after installation.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than give the entire script elevated privileges, just give them to the actual commands that need them. That is, rather than

```
$ sudo my_script
```

modify `my_script` to use `sudo` only on those commands that need it. For instance, if this is your script:

```
command1
command2
command3
command4
command5
```

and `command3` is the non-sudo command, modify your script to read

```
sudo command1
sudo command2
command3
sudo command4
sudo command5
```

In the process, think about whether `command1` actually *needs* to run with `sudo`, or it it can run just as well without. In that way, you should be able to greatly reduce the number of commands that actually need to be run with `sudo` in your script.

Comment: Currently that is what I have. But when it comes to that particular command it sends me a warning saying something like, "you shouldn't run this command with sudo" even though sudo is not written in front of that command. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the script, if not the whole thing.

Comment: I just added in that part of the script for you

Comment: Depending on your `sudo` configuration, this can require password input many times.  It's easier to run the script as the privileged user, but have it change back to the less privileged user as needed (i.e. `sudo -u "$SUDO_USER"` with a here-doc).

Comment: Easier, but less secure. Unless this is an ad-hoc script that will only be run a few times, it's worth the effort to correctly configure `sudo`.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your command is running with full privileges, it also has the privilege to demote its own privileges, for good or for the duration of one command, by running `su`.

```
touch /privileged
su -c 'cp /privileged /tmp/not' nobody
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are calling your script like:

`sudo script.sh`

And you do not want all of the commands within the script to run as root.

If your script is like:

```
apt-get install perl
apt-get install python
mv trash /home/user/
```

And you only want to run the first two commands as root you can specify a specific user for the third like:

`su -c "mv trash /home/user/" user`

Where `user` is the username you want to run the command as.

This will allow you to make a single sudo call at the parent level when you call the script.

If you don't want the username hardcoded, you can use a command like `logname` to get the username of the user that you are logged in as.

Comment: This looks promising. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the other answers, you can do this:

```sh
su -c "command" $SUDO_USER
```

Which will execute the command as the actual user who typed the `sudo` command

That's very useful when you are making scripts that require `sudo` to install something and write something in the user's `$HOME`